# Heroku NoMethodError  - Paperclip 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, paperclip

**Edit2~**

Hi All,

I solved my previous new error by changing my model file according to [this](http://codeglot.com/posts/68-upoading_pictures_to_apps_on_heroku). I don't know why but it solved it. I now have this error to deal with. : |

There is no key? method in my controller. Do I need to include it? If so, how?

```
NoMethodError in ProductPhotosController#index

undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass
Rails.root: /Users/cj3kim/Desktop/rails_projects/chocosite
```

Here is the full trace:

```
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/hide_actions.rb:36:in `visible_action?'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/hide_actions.rb:18:in `method_for_action'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:14:in `method_for_action'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:61:in `method_for_action'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:115:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:67:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:67:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:30:in `call'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:594:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:443:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in     `_run__3068104272435367366__call__4006997629250885704__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:61:in `call'
railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/Users/cj3kim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/cj3kim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/cj3kimactionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/hide_actions.rb:36:in `visible_action?'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/hide_actions.rb:18:in `method_for_action'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:14:in `method_for_action'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:61:in `method_for_action'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:115:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'  
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:67:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:67:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:30:in `call'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:594:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:443:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in     `_run__3068104272435367366__call__4006997629250885704__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:61:in `call'
railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/Users/cj3kim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/cj3kim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/cj3kim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in    start_thread'/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Here is my controller:

```
1 class ProductPhotosController < ApplicationController
2   # GET /product_photos
3   # GET /product_photos.json
4   def index
5     @product_photos = ProductPhoto.all
6 
7     respond_to do |format|
8       format.html # index.html.erb
9       format.json { render json: @product_photos }
10     end
11   end
```

Here is my model:

```
1 class ProductPhoto < ActiveRecord::Base
2   has_attached_file :image,
3     :style => {:small => "150x150"},
4     :storage => :s3,
5     :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml",
6     :path => "chocosite/:attachment/:style/:id.:extension"
7 end
```

**End edit**

---

**Edit~**

Heroku Load Error - Paperclip

The problem was a syntax error I found in my model. I have a new problem now

What I did:

This problem occurred on the local host with sqlite3 as db. I logged onto the s3 module and uploaded all the relevant folders that were once in **'public/system/images/000/000/'** to the folder **'images'** in the bucket choco_photos on s3. I also changed the URL and PATH to reflect it but I'm pretty sure I did something wrong.

Do the PATH AND URL file reflect where the image is stored and accessed on S3?

I will mention I am still confused about the configurations even after watching the railscast on paperclip.  I checked the docs AWS recommended but [it](http://rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3#s3_url_options-instance_method) didn't help. To be specific, I was confused by this statement:

```
# File 'lib/paperclip/storage/s3.rb', line 203

def s3_object style_name = default_style
  s3_bucket.objects[path(style_name).sub(%r{^/},'')]
end
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

More info:

```
LoadError in Product_photos#index

Showing /Users/cj3kim/Desktop/rails_projects/chocosite/app/views/product_photos/index.html.erb where line #4 raised:

cannot load such file -- aws-sdk (You may need to install the aws-sdk gem)
Extracted source (around line #4):

1: <div id="container_product_photos"> 
2: <% @product_photos.each do |photo| %>
3:   <div class="product_box" >
4:     /*#<%= link_to image_tag(photo.image.url(:small)), product_photo_path(photo) %>*/
5:     <p class='description'><%= photo.Name %> </p>
6:   </div> 
7: <% end %>
```

Here is my model file:

```
1 class ProductPhoto < ActiveRecord::Base
2   has_attached_file :image,
3     :storage => :s3,
4     :s3_credentials => {
5       :access_key_id => ENV['Access Key'],
6       :secret_access_key => ENV['Secret Key']
7     },
8     :bucket => ENV['choco_photos'],
9     :style => {
10       :small => "150x150"
11     },
12     :url => "/images/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
13     :path => "/images/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
14 end
```

~

Here is my gemfile:

```
12 group :production do
13     gem 'pg'
14 end
15 
16 gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.0.0'
17 gem 'paperclip', '~> 3.0'
18 gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 1.3.4'
```

**End of Edit**

---

Comment: please post the code for the model that has the paperlcip attachment

Answer (score 0):

For question 1: Heroku runs 1.9.2 on the Cedar stack, which you are on based on your app's URL. I believe the 1.9.1 is just a directory and does not actually related to the version ... I get the same "mismatch" between 1.9.1 in a folder name and my system actually running 1.9.2 or 1.9.3 (and I only run 1.9.2 or 1.9.3 via RVM).

You can verify the Heroku version by opening a Rails console on heroku ...

1. Open Terminal/Console
2. Navigate to your project directory
3. Type: heroku run console (this assumes you've installed the heroku gem or CLI tools)
4. Once the console loads, type: RUBY_VERSION (you should see either 1.9.2 or 1.9.3 output)

For the question 2: I had to alter how I had paperclip in my Gemfile. I use this and it works on Cedar:

```
gem 'paperclip', "~> 3.0"
gem "aws-sdk"
```

And in my related model:

```
has_attached_file :photo,
                :storage => :s3,
                :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
                :styles => {
                    :large => "600x480",
                    :medium => "330x230",
                    :small => "210x150",
                    :thumb => "90x90"
                },
                :path => 'images/products/:style/:filename'
```

And in my s3.yml file:

```
development: 
access_key_id: MYKEY
secret_access_key: MYSUPERSECRETACCESSKEY
bucket: bucketname
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for responding! It was originally a syntax error. I have a new problem now.